# Multi thread Dead Lock - Producer & Customer module using pthread lib

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, deadlock

Recently I'm investigate the pthread multi-thread lib and doing some example.

I try to write a Producer-Customer Module: There's a queue to store the Producer's product, and can be get by the Customer.

I set the queue MAX-SIZE as 20. When the queue is full, the Producer thread will wait, until the Customer thread consume one and nofity the Producer thread that he can start produce. And the same as Customer when the queue is empty, the Customer will wait until the Producer thread produce new one and notify him. :-)

I set the Customer thread consume faster than produce, it works fine as the log output in really what I expected. But, when I set the Producer thread consume faster than consume, it seems at last cause a **deadlock** :-(

I don't kown the reason, can anyone kindly read my code and give me some tips or how to modify the code?

Thanks!

```
#include "commons.h"

typedef struct tagNode {
    struct tagNode *pNext;
    char *pContent;
}NodeSt, *PNodeSt;

typedef struct {
    size_t  mNodeNum;
    size_t  mNodeIdx;
    PNodeSt mRootNode;
}WorkQueue;

#define WORK_QUEUE_MAX 20

static pthread_cond_t  g_adder_cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t g_adder_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static WorkQueue g_work_queue = {0};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
void *customer_thread_runFunc(void *usrdat){
    for( ; ; ) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&g_adder_mutex);{
        while( g_work_queue.mNodeNum == 0 ) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&g_adder_cond, &g_adder_mutex);
        }
/********************** CONSUME NEW PRODUCT ***********************/
        g_work_queue.mNodeNum --;

        if( g_work_queue.mRootNode->pNext != NULL ) {
            PNodeSt pTempNode = g_work_queue.mRootNode->pNext;
            free( g_work_queue.mRootNode->pContent );
            free( g_work_queue.mRootNode );
            g_work_queue.mRootNode = pTempNode;
        } else {
            free( g_work_queue.mRootNode->pContent );
            free( g_work_queue.mRootNode );
            g_work_queue.mRootNode = NULL;
        }
/********************** CONSUME PRODUCT END ***********************/
        // Nofity Producer Thread
        pthread_cond_signal(&g_adder_cond);
}pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_adder_mutex);

        // PAUSE FOR 300ms
        usleep(300); 
    }
    return NULL;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
void *productor_thread_runFunc( void *usrdat ) {
    for( ; ; ) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&g_adder_mutex); {
        char tempStr[64];
        PNodeSt pNodeSt = g_work_queue.mRootNode;

        while( g_work_queue.mNodeNum >= WORK_QUEUE_MAX ) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&g_adder_cond, &g_adder_mutex);
        }

/********************** PRODUCE NEW PRODUCT ***********************/
        g_work_queue.mNodeNum ++;
        g_work_queue.mNodeIdx ++;

        if( pNodeSt != NULL ) {
            for( ; pNodeSt->pNext != NULL; pNodeSt = pNodeSt->pNext );
            pNodeSt->pNext = malloc(sizeof(NodeSt));
            memset(pNodeSt->pNext, 0, sizeof(NodeSt));
            sprintf( tempStr, "production id: %d", g_work_queue.mNodeIdx);
            pNodeSt->pNext->pContent = strdup(tempStr);
        } else {
            g_work_queue.mRootNode = malloc(sizeof(NodeSt));
            memset(g_work_queue.mRootNode, 0, sizeof(NodeSt));
            sprintf( tempStr, "production id: %d", g_work_queue.mNodeIdx);
            g_work_queue.mRootNode->pContent = strdup(tempStr);
        }
/********************** PRODUCE PRODUCT END ***********************/
        // Nofity Customer Thread
        pthread_cond_signal(&g_adder_cond);
}pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_adder_mutex);

        // PAUSE FOR 150ms, faster than Customer Thread
        usleep(150); 
    }
    return NULL;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(void) {

    pthread_t pt1, pt3;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&pt1, &attr, customer_thread_runFunc, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pt3, &attr, productor_thread_runFunc, NULL);
    pthread_join(pt1, NULL);
    pthread_join(pt3, NULL);

    printf("MAIN - main thread finish!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your producer is waiting on the same condition as your consumer? This is definitely a source of trouble. Think about your code conceptually. What preconditions do the producer need before "producing"? As you mentioned, the buffer need to have space.

I did not look in detail, but you probably need an additional condition variable which is used by the producer (not the same as the consumer). The producer wait only if the queue is full. The consumer signal every times it successfully retrieve something from the queue.

EDIT: Reading the doc of pthread lib, One mutex can be used by two conditions

IDEA OF PSEUDOCODE :)

```
Mutex mqueue
Condition cprod, ccons

produce()
  mqueue.lock
  while the queue is full
     cprod.wait(mqueue)
  end
  do the production on queue
  mcons.signal
  mqueue.unlock
end produce

consume()
  mqueue.lock
  while the queue is empty
      ccons.wait(mqueue)
  end
  do the consumption on the queue
  cprod.signal
  mqueue.unlock
end consume
```

Preferably signal when you have the lock. Here I don't think the order make a difference.

Comment: they may be blocking on the same condition, but for the producer to block, it means that it has already sent at least WORK_QUEUE_MAX notifies to the consumer thread to let it know that it can continue working

Comment: @LefterisE actually they may use the same lock, but not block on the same condition. It just doesn't make sense. QUEUE EMPTY has a meaning only for the consumer, QUEUE FULL has a meaning only for the producer.

Comment: Thank you UmNyobe, I've tried to use double condition to re-write my program. But I'm afraid it still doesn't work. It will still finally result in deadlock.